# Equipment needed for comatose/bedridden persons outside a hospital?

Tags: science-based, biology, medicine

I'm still working on a short story series revolving around a resistance cell who fight against an oppressive, dystopian government. To make a long story short, they use a popular hotel chain as a front and are hiding POWs who were placed in medically induced comas (same as my protagonist). Unlike my protagonist though, who mostly recovered from muscle atrophy while walking with a cane, these patients were kept in comas for far longer, even going so far as years even. And until they fully recover, they're kept hidden in hotel rooms while a doctor and nurse help them.

What are the bare minimum of equipment, medical supplies, drugs, etc. needed to help them recover?

Comment: At the very basic, probably just a feeding tube and a tray to catch urine/poop. There are many diverse effects for people in a coma. Unless you have specific issues, like they can't breath, or this/that organ isn't working properly, it can be very bare bones.

Comment: How does this relate to the fundamental nature of a fictional world, rather than the exigencies of the story you're writing?  Am voting to close for that reason.

Comment: Are these folks still in comas or are they just super weak from having been in a coma?

Comment: Hi Nathan, this is a cool premise but we'll need a little bit more information to answer it coherently. Willk's point is especially relevant, but in order to answer it I suspect we'll need a time frame (how long) in order to minimize equipment, otherwise you'll get answers that use less equipment but take longer vs high-tech, intensive efforts that work much more quickly but require a lot. I've voted to place your question on hold so you don't get swamped with unhelpful answers before you get a chance to [edit] your question.

Comment: You might want to check out our sister site [medicalsciences.se] for this. [Their subject scope](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) appears to be a reasonable fit for this question. We can migrate your question if you'd like; if so, "flag" the question for moderator attention and request migration (and specify the target site).

Comment: Check into the amount of care a comatose patient requires.  You will require people to turn, them, clean them, massage them.  You will have serious muscle atrophy.  I wouldn't be surprised if you need 1 carer per patient if they are also to have an additional life.  This is going to be hard to hide from a repressive government.